GDAL Exception when using in AutoCAD .Net Plugin
I have installed GDAL and GDAL.Native v3.9.1 packages. Console applications work well, but when I use it in AutoCAD Class Library project, it always raises the exception:

The type initializer for 'OSGeo.GDAL.GdalPINVOKE' threw an exception.

I am using Visual Studio 2019. The application is being compiled using .NET Framework 4.8.1.
The default GdalConfiguration.cs file is set with execution path of output directory where gdal folder is installed.
// Add directories
AddDllDirectory(nativePath);
AddDllDirectory(Path.Combine(nativePath, "plugins"));

// Set the additional GDAL environment variables.
string gdalData = Path.Combine(gdalPath, "data");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GDAL_DATA", gdalData);
Gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_DATA", gdalData); // <------------ Exception!

string driverPath = Path.Combine(nativePath, "plugins");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GDAL_DRIVER_PATH", driverPath);

Gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_DRIVER_PATH", driverPath); // <--- Exception!

The lines with comments generate the exception.
Any idea to counter this issue?

You may be calling the wrong function, https://gdal.org/api/cpl.html#_CPPv418CPLSetConfigOptionPKcPKc

I think you need to set the Environment Variable path where gdal_wrap.dll is located:
private static void InitializeNativeDllPath(string subfolder)
{
    var nativeDllPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, pathWhereDllIs);
    var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $"{nativeDllPath};{path}");
}

Then register the Gdal first:
OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.AllRegister();

